# How to fetch only english comments from facebook?

Tags: java, facebook4j

I fetched the comments from facebook using facebook4j and stored in text file, but I want only English comments for further processing,ignoring Spanish , Japanese,French.

I tried using regex in Java but not getting the exact regular expression for accepting only English sentences/comments.

Comment: A regex won’t help with identifying languages. Maybe use a spell checker or an online tool.

Comment: How are you saving the texts? Maybe you should separate out the text file for each language so that it make it easier for you to read it later. You should have the file format somewhat like, comments_EN.text for english, comment_ES.txt for spanish and comments_JP for japanese etc..

Comment: I don't know facebook4j but you can filter the fetched comments based on the score provided by a lib similar to [language-detector](https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector). It won't be perfect, especially with short comments.